# Why do I get strange artifacts in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, visual-artifacts

I am drawing with pen tool, and 1 pt size stroke without fill.
When I draw a palm, for example, I use shape builder + to tell illustrator what is what, I use gradient fill, I remove stroke, and sometime I get this after hours of work which is very frustrating.
[image]

For me it looks like two paths touching for some time, and not touching on some parts, and shape builder gets confused.
Well, I do a normal process, and it is usual there will be paths one over another, and in future how would I solve this, if it is solveable.
No matter how much I zoom, I can not use shape builder to join these artifacts or paths or whatever they are with one or another bigger shape.

This is Paths View
[image]

As you can "hardly" see. there are paths one over another, so what can I do to merge them into one path, remove extra path, or whatever is solution to get around this?

Comment: Not sure this is actually a "duplicate". In any event, if you want just one shape.. drag the Shape Builder tool across all the objects.